# Address of address of array

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

If I define an variable:
`int (**a)[30];`
It is pointer. This pointer points to a pointer which points to an array of 30 ints.
How to declare it or initialize it?

```
int (**a)[10] = new [10][20][30];
int (**a)[10] = && new int[10];
```

All doesn't work.

Comment: Your question is backwards. You should first figure out what data structure you want and then how to represent it. If you want a fixed-size 3d array, just declare `a` as `int a[10][20][30];` and be done with it.

Comment: I can see the merit of the question, but not the merit of the thing you are trying to do. Are you sure you need that many indirections?

Comment: Java programmer? In C++ you don't need pointers everywhere

Comment: There are many ways to give `a` a value. The question is what you want to do with it.

Comment: I _cannot_ figure out how to allocate a dynamic array of pointers to `int[30]`, (which would match what he wants) without a typedef.  Fascinating.

Comment: @MooingDuck: How do you know what he wants? The two tries shown above attempt to do completely different things.

Comment: @interjay: Completely unrelated to what the OP wants, I cannot find any expression `int (**a)[10] = new ????;` that compiles without a typedef.  Period.

Comment: (Also, a dynamic array of pointers to `int[30]` is about the only "useful" purpose I can think of for such a type.)

Comment: Although, in real code: `std::vector<std::array<int, 30>*>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct answer to your question of how to initialize `a` (whether or not that's what you actually need) is

```
int (**a)[10] = new (int (*)[10]);
```

I don't think this is actually what you want though; you probably want to initialize the pointer to point to an actual array, and either way `std::vector` is the better way to do it.

Comment: Interesting that `new (int (*)[10])` compiles but `new (int (*)[10])[30]` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an answer to the question as it stands, then you can do this kind of thing:

```
int a[30];
int (*b)[30] = &a;
int (**c)[30] = &b;
```

But it's unlikely to be what you want, as other people have commented. You probably need to clarify your underlying goal - people can only speculate otherwise.

---

Just to follow on from MooingDuck's remark, I can in fact see a way to do it without the typedef, but not directly:

```
template <typename T>
T *create(T *const &)
{
    return new T;
}

int (**a)[30] = create(a);
```

It's not pretty though.

Comment: I got this: `typedef int(*array)[30]; int (**a)[30] = new array[10];`, but I can't figure out how to do it without a typedef.

Comment: @MooingDuck: That's definitely a more useful answer - I can't see an obvious way to do it without the typedef though either.

Comment: Isn't `int (**a)[30] = create(a);` undefined behavior, since `a` is uninitialized? I'm not sure if this prevents it, but `create(T *const &)` may work.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Whoops, true - I guess it will read `a` in passing it to the function, even though it's not read within the function.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to get by writing `&(&var)`? This is an equivalent of `address of address of a block of memory`. Doing things like this just to satisfy the number of `*` in your code makes no sense.

Think about it - *how can you get an address of an address*? Even if, by some sheer luck or weird language tricks you manage to do it, there no way it will work.

Comment: You're right that `&&var` makes no sense (it doesn't even compile), because it's the address of a _temporary_ address.  If you make that middle one a non-temporary, then an address of an address is actually a common thing when interacting with C libraries.

Comment: @MooingDuck It is then not an address of an address, but an address of a variable which holds another address.

Comment: Ah, I think the confusion is "what is an address" then.  Because both cases have an _object_ that holds the address, the difference is in one case the object is an rvalue, and in the other case the object is an lvalue.